# Build objects from YAML and include non-object attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I'm mocking out some sample data for a landing page. I'm loading the objects from a YAML file. I need to additionally assign some "accessory" data to each object that are not attributes from my schema.

```
@data = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/sample_foo.yml")


---
- !ruby/object:Foo
  attributes:
    username: jdoe
    text: Hello World
    customer_type: A   # Not a Foo attribute
- !ruby/object:Foo
  attributes:
    username: mnort
    text: Hi
    customer_type: B   # Not a Foo attribute
```

This doesn't work because `customer_type` is not a `Foo` attribute.

I would just use hashes, but I need to load the data as objects to use pre-existing view partials for these objects.

Comment: Out of topic - Why storing your fixtures files .yml in the `lib/tasks/` directory? Why not `db/fixtures/` ?

Comment: I'm not sure why I did that. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you have several files like this that need to be loaded at the Application start, I would create a folder for these files, something like `db/fixtures/on_boot/*.yml`